# Prevent an incoming call from stopping the application execution(Angular, Ionic)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, streaming, ionic6, incoming-call

I am developing an app with angular and ionic 6. In the app you can do streaming and when you receive an incoming call the streaming stops. Is there any way to block incoming calls or show them as a floating notification over my app?

Comment: there is a way but its a bit still complicated, if you inject in ur constructor(private plt: Platform), you can use this.plt.pause.subscribe(res => { ... }) & this.plt.resume.subscribe(res => { ... }) so the pause is when you get a phone call so u can pause your stream till the phone call end and resume when the phone call ends, but still the complication part is that if that if u minimize the app, it will also pause the stream so thats a fix but still with a bit with of complication ..

Comment: @MostafaHarb thank you for your response but I don't want to pause the streaming I want to block calls or make them less invasive

Comment: its not thing u can control, phone calls are built in the software, so in case there was a way though i don't think so but that could be manually and not as programing... if u see whatsapp way how they deal with this, they put the users on hold in case of phone call so that's the default behavior...

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible. Android or iOS does not allow that to happen and never will.

Comment: That's not true when I'm playing some games, I receibe an incoming call and it appears silently as a pop up notification. The game is never interrupted.